# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: s when updating in SQL Server

Tags: c#, angular, rest

I'm using C# to build a Rest API for updating user photo:

```
    [Route("api/ce/updateFoto")]
    [HttpPut]
    [ActionName("updateFoto")]
    public string updateFoto(int id, [FromBody] string photo)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();

        try
        {
            JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(photo);
            JToken jUser = jObject["user"];
            string photoString = (string) jUser["photo"];
            cnn.myConnection.Open();
            cmd.Connection = cnn.myConnection;
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "update user set photo = convert(VARBINARY(max), '"+ photoString +"') where id=" + id;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            cnn.myConnection.Close();
        }
        return "ok";
    }
```

And as front end, I'm using Angular 4. My code for calling the api :

```
URL = 'http://SERVER/Project/api/ce/updateFoto?id=';

   SavePhoto(userAsJsonString: string, id: string) {
      return this.http.put(this.URL + id, userAsJsonString, this.options)
     .map((res: Response) => {
      res.json();
    });
```

The httpPut response when updating returns `200 OK`, but the photo is not updated, and I'm getting this response:

> Response {_body: ""Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: s"", status: 200, ok:}

Can someone help me ? I'm not getting it! I tried also the get request instead of put, but my photo string is too long! So I must implement the put request with the body.

Comment: Have you debugged the API? Do you receive the file on that side?

Comment: no i didnt , i dont know how actually, but the json is getting fine in the api

Comment: Just add a breakpoint at the first line of your action method and check if you see the value. (Use F9) to trigger the breakpoint. And obviously you should debug the API (not run).

Comment: actually i publish the api on a windows server so when i used its already published

Comment: That's kinda weird that you've published  an untested API directly, but anyway you should have some logs perhaps to debug.

Comment: i'm newbie in that ! i found the errors when using the api ! thats what i'm doing ! but this one ..

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 0):

What is `cnn` and `cnn.myConnection`? Is this a global static connection? If so get rid of it and create a new connection instance each time it is needed. Connection pooling is already handled for you by the framework so creating a new managed connection is relatively cheap.

What is the value of `userAsJsonString` in your client side code? Are you posting a `json` object? If so you should create a matching c# model class and use that as the incoming method argument, not a string.

You should use parameters, do not use string concatenation for your incoming values. Not doing this leaves your code open to sql injection attacks. Using parameters makes your code easier to read, allows sql server to reuse any execution plans, and prevents possible bugs due to un-escaped string values.

```
cmd.CommandText = "update user set photo = @photo where id= @id";
// convert photo to a byte array
// I am not sure what the string is being sent, perhaps its base64 or hex or something else?
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@photo", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1){Value = photoByteArray});
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int){Value = id});
```

If there was an error do not return status 200 in your web api code. You can do this by not returning `string` but returning `IHttpActionResult` if its web api or changing the `Response.StatusCode` if using MVC. Status 200 means everything worked in the web api, in the case of an exception this is not true. Which status to return depends on what happened, pick an appropriate [http status code](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

Finally you are losing all the good information from your exception. Log the whole thing including the Type, Message, and the stack trace. Repeat this for any inner exception recursively.